# Centered Divs Shift Vertically When Text Is Added

Tags: html, css

Why is it that when you add text into one of two centered `<div>`s that it shifts vertically?

Here's an example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/jRSt9/)

Two child divs with `display:inline-block;` centered by the parent div using `text-align:center;` are centered right next to each other nicely when there is nothing inside of them, but as soon as there is even one letter of text that div shifts vertically.

This happens only with text. How do you fix this?

EDIT: This happens with `img` elements too. Am I the only one that finds this odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `vertical-align` to either `top`, `bottom`, or `middle`.. This will control the alignment no matter the content.

EDIT: The reason why this happens is because `vertical-align` defaults to `baseline`, which attempts to align the baselines of the content. For example, two boxes with text, one with twice as much as the other, would be aligned in such a way as to have the last line of text in each box vertically aligned to each other.

Because your one box has no content, the baseline is set to the bottom of the box.

Comment: why is it that only text shifts the div vertically? edit: I think img tags move it as well.

Comment: Sorry for deleting and re-adding my comments, but I've got a better explanation.. I believe the proper term would be 'baseline alignment', where it tries to align the baselines of the content by default. The box which has no content essentially has no baseline so it lines the bottom up with the baseline of the text content. (You can see this in action by adding more lines of text.. the box will shift upwards accordingly)